# ASP.net asp-for not popping options

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am trying to realise why the asp-for="" does not pop up the options that are available to choose, this a sample example of what I am trying to find out.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
<form method="post">
    <label asp-for="Date">Hello</label>



</form>
</div>
```

The Date is underlined in red as an error.

These are the models

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZja7.png

This is the specific model I want to call

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BirdProject.Model
{
    public partial class SpotLog
    {
        public int SpotId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
        public string? MetalRing { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        public virtual Person? EmailNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual BirdBto? MetalRingNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The connection to the database is properly working as I have scaffolded the database information in a database first approach.

Comment: Do you suspect this is a bug with Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? Is there any evidence that intellisense should be showing you a list?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I did see them popping out in previous projects, also you can see it in many youtube videos.